# connect to ibm mq broker using activemq client

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I used IBM MQs on my local machine to connect to a remote IBM MQ Queue Manager on a client machine for sending and receiving messages.
Due to some issues I need to uninstall IBM MQs on my end.
Can I connect to the client remote queue manager using Apache ActiveMQ? (With SSL)

If possible please guide me how to proceed with it.
If not please suggest any alternative solutions to connect.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Connect to it using the WebSphere MQ Client.  It is freely downloadable as [SupportPac MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75) and includes support for several languages, including C and Java.  Rather than just grabbing the jar files, please install the entire client distribution.  IBM includes a number of diagnostic utilities, tracing and so forth in that distribution.  These make debugging much easier and IBM requires them to be installed if you open a support ticket.  Since the client is free, requiring the diagnostic tools to be installed seems reasonable.

The documentation for the client is [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp).

Active MQ uses a different wire protocol and its client won't work with WebSphere MQ.

Comment: WebSphere MQ would be a tricky solution to send and receive messages .what he needs is RFHUTILC to be able to do it much more easily.

Comment: Assuming RFHUTILC is in fact what OP needs, it pre-reqs the WMQ Client. The WMQ client provides the API to program against whereas RFHUTILC provides a human interactive GUI and these are not substitutes for one another.  Since OP's replacing a queue manager, I'm assuming the API is required. Fortunately, any program written for WMQ bindings mode should work as a client without modification.  That said, can you elaborate on how WMQ is "tricky"?

Comment: Well i primarily use WMQ for managing/monitoring my QM's, Queues and Channels. No disrespect but i don't find WMQ to be efficient way of loading/browsing/offloading messages. Also RFHUTILC commandline can be used to load and dump messages by writing DOS Batch files.

Comment: I think we're talking about different things. RFHUTILC is great for the tasks you describe but I don't believe OP is trying to achieve those tasks. This is a B2B interface where OP's customer has a full QMgr and, until recently, so too did OP. Assuming that OP has some app that executes business transactions, the question is how to get it to work without a local QMgr. The answer to that question is to use the client libs instead of bindings. If you believe OP is asking some other question about productivity tools, why not write it up as a separate answer? If right, you'll get votes.